# 画像を配列に格納し、NSUserDefaultsに配列を保存し、そこから画像を取り出したい

Tags: swift2

入力側ビューコントローラーで画像と文章を登録して、出力側ビューコントローラーのテーブルビューで一覧表示する写真付きメモ帳のようなアプリをつくっています。

ImageViewに表示された画像を配列に格納し、NSUserDefaultsに画像の配列を保存し、別のビューコントローラーのテーブルビューのセル上のImageViewに配列から取り出した画像を順繰りに表示したいのですが、画像が表示されず、行き詰まっています。

1.画像を配列に格納する
2.その配列をNSUserDefaultsに保存する
3.そこから画像を取り出しテーブルビューのセル上に順繰りに表示する
のどの段階でミスが生じているのか分かりません。

ビルドは問題なくできています。
よろしくお願いします。

入力側ビューコントローラー

```
     //配列を作成
     var imageList:[AnyObject] = [""]

     let ud = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

     //配列をNSUserDefaultsに作成
     ud.setObject(imageList, forKey:"imageList")
     ud.synchronize()

     //ImageViewの画像を配列にいれ、配列をNSUserDefaultsに同期
     if var imageList:[AnyObject] = ud.objectForKey("imageList")! as! [AnyObject]  {

     if let image = displayImage.image {
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
        imageList.append(imageData!)
        ud.setObject(imageList, forKey: "imageList")
        ud.synchronize()
        }
    }
```

出力側ビューコントローラー

```
    //画像データの取得
    let imageList = ud.arrayForKey("imageList")
    if let image : [UIImage] = imageList as? [UIImage] {
        cell!.displayImage.image = image[indexPath.row]
    }
```

Comment: `NSData`型を`UIImage`型にキャストすることはできませんが？それと、Xcode8リリースとともに、Swift3も正式リリースになりましたので、Swift2が対象になる質問は、タグを**swift2**にするなどして、明確な区別をしていただけたら、回答しやすくなります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。タグを変更しました。  
画像一枚だけならば以下のコードでキャストして表示できたのですが、画像の配列となると、どうキャストして良いのか分かりません。 
  
      if let imageData = userDefaults.objectForKey("imageData") as? NSData, image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            // UserDefaultsから画像が取得出来た場合ImageViewのimageに設定
            loadImageView.image = image
        }
  
このコードは下記サイトから引用したものです。  
https://teratail.com/questions/34233

Answer (score 0):

NSKeyedArchiveObjectあたり調べてみたらどうでしょうか　NSDataにアーカイブできますよ

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
出力側ビューコントローラーを下記のコードにすることで順繰りに取り出し、表示することができました。
nagonsoftwareさん、ucbさんありがとうございました。

```
    if let imageData = ud.arrayForKey("imageList")![indexPath.row] as? NSData, image = UIImage(data: imageData) {

        cell!.memoImage.image = image
    }
```

Comment: `if let imageArray = ud.arrayForKey("imageList") as? [NSData], let image = UIImage(data: imageArray[indexPath.row])`としたほうが、`!`を使わずに済むので、より安全になりますね。